# Kaniko multistage build and adding multiple git repositories

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, odoo, kaniko

Im moving away from docker dind builds now by transition to gitlab kubernetes executor. We are investigating if i could use Kaniko for this process.
Is the correct strategy to extend the kaniko image with git and then clone in the script like below or is there any better way in these scenarios

```
build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.9.0-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - <install-git>
    - <perform-clone>
    - <perform-clone>
    - <perform-clone>
    - /kaniko/executor
      --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
      --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Dockerfile"
      --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_kaniko.html

The issue is that we have the
https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/odoo/16/debian-11/Dockerfile

And we want to extend this by the community addions git libs

```
    - git clone -b 16.0 https://github.com/OCA/web.git ${ODOO_INSTALL_DIR}/odoo16-oca-web
    - git clone -b 16.0 https://github.com/OCA/server-tools.git ${ODOO_INSTALL_DIR}/odoo16-oca-server-tools
    - git clone -b 16.0 https://github.com/OCA/connector.git ${ODOO_INSTALL_DIR}/odoo16-oca-connector
```

And add them in the multistage build by a custom Dockerfile

```
FROM bitnami/odoo:16
ARG odoo_dir=/app/odoo
# Since we include multiple repos it is not possible to have a build context, making it not possible
# To work with Dockerignore
ADD odoo16-oca-connector ${odoo_dir}/odoo16-oca-connector
ADD odoo16-oca-server-tools ${odoo_dir}/odoo16-oca-server-tools 
ADD odoo16-oca-web ${odoo_dir}/odoo16-oca-web

USER root
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/bitnami/scripts/odoo/entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "/opt/bitnami/scripts/odoo/run.sh" ]
```

Alternative solutions or advices getting forward.

Comment: Hi @ZerNox,  were you able to achieve this by adding git to kaniko image?